# Radgrid: access new row on add button event

Tags: telerik, radgrid, radgridview

Does anyone have idea how can i access a control within the radgrid row that has been dynamically created on the click of add button?

Comment: show your grid declaration please

Comment: Thanks for your replying Steven :), i found a way around to achieve this! :)